# Determine which tile is clicked in a window

Tags: c++, tiles, sfml, tile

I am drawing a tilemap on a SFML renderwindow. I want to determine which tile is clicked by the user, but I just cant seem to find a solution. First of all, each tile has 32 width and height.
What i try at the moment : Get the position of the click. Loop trough the tilemap until a tile is found which position is between 100. So if I click on (100,100) the tile should begin at (96,96) but this does not seem to work.

[image: Tiles]

Here is my code snippet from the function getTile(mousepos x,mousepos y)

```
Tile* TileMap::getTile(int x, int y)
{
    Tile *t = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < tilemap.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < tilemap[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if(x > tilemap[i][j].sprite.getPosition().x
            && x < (tilemap[i][j].sprite.getPosition().x+32))
            {
                if(y > tilemap[i][j].sprite.getPosition().y
                && y < (tilemap[i][j].sprite.getPosition().y+32))
                {
                    t = &tilemap[i][j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, I am going to assume that you are basing your tilemap on a 2d array of Tiles: tilemap[x][y]. I am also going to assume that tilemap[0][0] is the top left tile.

There should be a much easier way to find out which tile is being clicked on instead of testing every single tile.

If you are at 100,100 and tiles are 32x32, then we can get the x and y of the tile within the tilemap by doing something as simple as:

x = 100 / 32 = 3

y = 100 / 32 = 3

Therefor the tile in your tilemap that corresponds to a mouse position of (100,100) is tilemap[3][3].

Comment: 100 % 32 = 4, because the modulo operator returns the rest of the division. 30 % 32 = 30

Comment: Whoops. My mistake.  Yes, you want the division operator not modulo.  As long as you use integer division, you should be safe.  I believe most, if not all, of the units used should be integer (mouse coordinate, 2d array indices, tile dimensions)

Comment: This equation should work if your map is not offset by a "view" or something.  You will have to add a translation factor into the formula, but that is not much harder.  Just something to keep in mind as you evolve your tile map!